# Столбцы в flexbox не правильно отображаются

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 таблицы, в маленьком окне они смотрятся симметрично, но как только разворачиваю на весь экран, левый столбец уходит вверх.

Как это решить ?

```css
html {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: #d1d1d1;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.colr {
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 100%;
  /* Размер шрифта */
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  /* Параметры линии под текстом */
  font-weight: normal;
  /* Убираем жирное начертание */
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* Расстояние от текста до линии */
}

.colr2 {
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 80%;
  /* Размер шрифта */
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000000;
  /* Параметры линии под текстом */
  font-weight: normal;
  /* Убираем жирное начертание */
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* Расстояние от текста до линии */
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* отображение блоков ровномерно
-------------------- */

.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-reverse {
  margin: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 90px;
  background: #afafaf;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span class="colr"><b>ЧАО "СЕВГОК" ЦПО 1 УЧАСТОК №2</b></span>
</header>
<span class="colr2"><b>Гистограмми распределения гранулометрического состава окатышей по чашевым окомкователям</b></span>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    1 CHARTS
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2 CHARTS
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    3 CHARTS
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-reverse">
  <div class="flex-item">
    4 CHARTS
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    5 CHARTS
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    6 CHARTS
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оберните их и уже обертке задайте display flex.

Comment: Почему `header` был за `body`?

Comment: Поставил header  перед body ,а ничего не поменялось

Comment: Ну в данном примере не изменилось бы, просто это уже плохо, надо быть внимательнее. Весь контент должен быть в `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex - правило` для `flex - контента` не будет работать, если нет `flex - контейнера`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  font-family: helvetica;
  background: #d1d1d1;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.colr {
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.colr2 {
  color: #2f2d2d;
  font-size: 80%;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* это то что добавлено -------------------- */

.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}


/* --------------------- -------------------- */

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* отображение блоков ровномерно -------------------- */

.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  /*float: left; зачем flex - контенту float*/
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column-reverse {
  margin: auto;
  /*float: right; зачем flex - контенту float*/
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #c4c4c4;
  border-radius: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 90px;
  background: #afafaf;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span class="colr"><b>ЧАО "СЕВГОК" ЦПО 1 УЧАСТОК №2</b></span>
</header>
<span class="colr2"><b>Гистограмми распределения гранулометрического состава окатышей по чашевым окомкователям</b></span>
<!-- это то что добавлено -->
<div class="main-flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      1 CHARTS
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      2 CHARTS
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      3 CHARTS
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column-reverse">
    <div class="flex-item">
      4 CHARTS
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      5 CHARTS
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      6 CHARTS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```